# inet_pton not working

Tags: php

I am trying to use to turn an IP address into a numerical string for mysql storage using the inet_pton() in the PHP code, yet this function either returns nothing or this: '�?i'
NOTE: The IP address is a standard IPv4 (and not my localhost)

My code is: echo inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

Comment: "This function converts a human readable IPv4 or IPv6 address (if PHP was built with IPv6 support enabled) into an address family appropriate 32bit or 128bit binary structure." In other words, not to any readable format.

Answer (score 6):

The output of `inet_pton()` is a binary string - nothing printable in most of the cases. You can try this with

```
echo inet_pton("65.66.67.68");
```

**EDIT** after feedback from @YWSW the question is, how to split the IP address in the string "173.63.155.19" in the 4 bytes 173, 63, 155 and 119

This could be achieved by

```
$ip_bytes=inet_pton($ip_string);

$ip_byte0=ord($ip_bytes[0]);
$ip_byte1=ord($ip_bytes[1]);
$ip_byte2=ord($ip_bytes[2]);
$ip_byte3=ord($ip_bytes[3]);
```

$ip_byte[0..3] are the 4 bytes you need.

Please understand, that I do NOT endorse storing an IP address in the DB as 4 ints!

Comment: And you really have tried exactly `echo inet_pton("65.66.67.68");` to understand the issue? Not your IP address, but really "65.66.67.68" ?

Comment: hmmm. that does work ('ABCD'). I was trying: echo inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); which did not work for me. What do you think the issue is?

Comment: As I pointed out, the output of `inet_pton()` is normally NOT PRINTABLE - it only is with specially crafted IP addresses. The one I gave is one. What is your expected output for `inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`

Comment: well, for the case in question $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is 173.63.155.19. I want to turn that IP address into a string of integers for better mysql storage

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
echo inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Is converting a readeable IP from a normal string to a binary string (that my include NULL chars and other strange values, and therefore unreadeable).
To represent your binary ip value back into a readeable string, use bin2hex(). Which will convert binary values into readeable hex strings:

```
echo bin2hex(inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

It doesn't quite end there: next matter is to consider which format you want to display it: IPv6 usually displays each binary byte as hex and has ':' every fourth hex, whereas IPv4 usually displays each binary byte as numerical values (not hex!) and has a '.' after each byte-to-number representation.